# Google Analytics will not track each page with ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, angular-ui-router

EDITED (5/25/2018): I still haven't got a solution to make this work. I use the code based on https://dev.to/jordanirabor/using-google-analytics-with-angular-930

This is my first time using GA and I hope you can help me make this work.

I'm using Angular SPA with UI-router and I created a tracking id (I used the fake one in the code below) on Google Analytics. It works only on the front page `index.html` as I tested on GA, but it will not track other routing pages. It seems that the `run` block with the tracking ID is not doing anything when I was on GA to test each page. Im not sure what Im missing.

Also the `<div ui-view></div>` it will not display a text inside the `{{ title }}` and that tells me something on `app-test.js` is not working.

Index.html -

```
<script>
    (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
        i[r] = i[r] || function() {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
        a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
        a.async = 1;
        a.src = g;
        m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
</script>
```

app-test.js

```
myApp.config(['urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){ 
'use strict';

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');
$stateProvider
    .state("main", {
    url: "/main",
    templateUrl: "main.html",
    controller: function ($rootScope, $scope) {
                $rootScope.title = 'SCIS, Sorenson Community Interpreting Services, Interpreting, interpreter, interpreters, Sorenson Communication, SVRS';
                $rootScope.metaDescription = 'Sorenson Community Interpreting Services for over 15 years, Interpreting for medical,Interpreting for business, Interpreting for legal, Interpreting for educational,VRI, Video Remote Interpreting';
                setCurrentNavItem('main'); 
                $scope.title = 'This is the homepage'
    } 
    }).state("request", {
    url: "/request",
    templateUrl: "views/request-interpreter.html",
    controller: function ($rootScope, $scope) {
                $rootScope.title = 'text here';
                $rootScope.metaDescription = 'text here';
                setCurrentNavItem('request');
                $scope.title = 'This is the request interpreting page'
            }
....
```

Run block -

```
app.run(['$location', '$window','$transitions', function($location, $window, $transitions){
    $window.ga('create', 'UA-2121548-23', 'auto');
    $transitions.onSuccess({}, function(){
          $window.ga('send', 'pageview', $location.path());
    });
}])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the nature of Google Analytics with a SPA, but the good news is that you can manually call the same methods to simulate navigating around different pages. What we do (after ensuring that the tracker has been instantiated) is use the `$stateChangeSuccess` event to send a page view to GA:

**If using TypeScript:**

```
// wire up the event (we use controller as syntax and typescript - hence the types)
this.$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
    (event: ng.IAngularEvent, 
     toState: ng.ui.IState,
     toParams: any, 
     fromState: ng.ui.IState, 
     fromParams: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.$window.ga('set', 'page', this.$location.path());
    this.$window.ga('send', 'pageview');
});
```

**If not using TypeScript:**

```
// wire up the event (we use controller as syntax)
this.$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
    (event, 
     toState,
     toParams, 
     fromState, 
     fromParams) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.$window.ga('set', 'page', this.$location.path());
    this.$window.ga('send', 'pageview');
});
```

**Update:** There is one more piece of code that we call to set up the tracker. You'll need the `UA-...` tracking ID from your GA account. You can put this in your `.run()` method:

```
this.$window.ga('create', <replace this with your UA-*** tracking ID>, 'auto');
```

If you don't use controller as syntax simply remove the `this.`.

Comment: Ok, after I updated the code and it stopped loading the pages - it only displays the main page without the header and the footer before I try to test it on GA. Is it something that is blocking from loading pages?

Comment: Hmm, I can't remember why we put the `event.preventDefault()` in there, but you could try removing that. However, since this is the `$stateChangeSuccess` event I wouldn't expect that to cause an issue. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, two errors in the console: 1.) app-test.js - ERROR: Expected ')' 2.) [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument." Also I removed the `event.preventDefault();` same errors occurred.

Comment: Ah, my bad - it was a bad cut 'n paste. I left out the `);` on the end. I just updated the snippet in my answer.

Comment: Updated and still getting the same error: `(event: ng.IAngularEvent, toState: ng.ui.IState, toParams: any, fromState: ng.ui.IState, fromParams: any)` is where the error is coming from `app-test.js - ERROR: Expected ')' `

Comment: Are you using Typescript? If not you will need to remove all the types.

Comment: Yeah, that cleared the errors in the console. Going to test it on GA...

Comment: I'm curious to hear if this ended up working for you.

Comment: Regarding to GA, I'm only getting the homepage content area, not from each page...

Comment: Throw a `console.log()` to make sure the event is firing. Where did you put the `$scope.$on()` stuff? If you are not using controller as syntax you'll have to remove the `this.` on those 3 lines.

Comment: I removed 3 `this.` and added `console.log(myApp); return myApp;` See updated code above. Its not doing anything. Maybe its because the console.log() is in the wrong line or something?

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting errors because you haven't injected `$scope`.

Comment: Should I add `$scope` inside `run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location', '$window'];` ?

Comment: Yes, and the function signature as well.

Comment: `function run($rootScope, $location, $window)` should be `function run($rootScope, $location, $window, $scope)` (assuming you add `$scope` in the last position of your injection array).

Comment: Ok, I checked on GA nothing is working just the index page...:-( are the `$rootScope` and `$Scope` two different things? If not I should remove `$rootScope`?

Comment: I forgot one key line of code to create the GA tracker. I've updated the answer to include the line.

Comment: Yeah, its already there `$window.ga('create', 'UA-1235489-32', 'auto');` since the beginning unless its in the wrong line of the codes.

Comment: You should delete that tracker ID from your comment because someone could potentially use it for nefarious purposes.

Comment: Its a fake one :-)

Comment: Ha, gotcha. Well, I'm stumped because this is literally the code we use to simulate getting pageviews in our app. I just verified that things are displaying properly in GA and they are. Is it possible GA is not lagging behind a little?

Comment: Oh, man...I forgot you can't inject `$scope` in `.run`, so try going back and using `$rootScope.$on('stateChangeSuccess', ...)`.

Comment: This logic has now been deprecated with the last version of Router UI (1.0.0+)